# Is it possible to insert a new condition to a while loop mid-loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have a `while(notFound)` loop. This loop first checks stuff that specified in option "a" however  some point in the loop that option becomes "b" and in that case I need to somewhat update the loop to:

`while((notFound) &&(trCollator.compare(data.getSurname("a"),current.data().getSurname("a")) == 0))`

So are there any syntax that cheks the second part only if the option equals "b"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```java
while((notFound)){
  if(option.equals("a") || (option.equals("b") &&(trCollator.compare(data.getSurname("a"),current.data().getSurname("a")) == 0))){
          //execute code...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add in the else block the `break` statement to make it more appropriate so that when both the conditions (in `while` and in `if`) are false, the loop should terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You can toogle an additional condition using a boolean implication:
»*If ... then ...*« which is the same as `!... || ...`.

```
String option = "a";
while (notFound && (!"b".equals(option) ||
       trCollator.compare(data.getSurname("a"), current.data().getSurname("a")) == 0))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a flag that says whether you need to check it or not.

```
boolean flag = false;
while (notFound &&
       (!flag || trCollator.compare(data.getSurname("a"),current.data().getSurname("a") == 0)) {

     ...
     if (somethingOrOther)
         flag = true;
     ...

}
```

Initially, `flag` is false, so `!flag` is true, so the second clause of the logical-or operator is skipped.  Later, `!flag` is false, so the second clause is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an interface
public interface myInterface {
    public boolean compareTo();
}

// create two classes 
public class aa implements myInterface {

        @Override
        public boolean compareTo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
}

public class bb implements myInterface {
    String surname;
    String currentSurname;
    
    bb(String surname, String currSurname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.currentSurname = currSurname;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean compareTo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.surname.equals(this.currentSurname);
    }
}

// in while loop when you hit some condition change the value of mObj like below

        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tmp =n.nextInt();
        
        myInterface mObj = new aa();
        
        while(tmp > 0 && mObj.compareTo()) {
            // some condition
            if(tmp == 5) {
                mObj = new bb("kumar", "sharma");
            }
            tmp--;
            
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: In fact you can add any kind of comparison within compareTo function of class bb. or can have any no of similar classes for each type of comparison.